# XML Parser that works for both browser and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, browser, node-modules

Problem at hand: I have XML on the client side and the server side, but there's no consistent way to parse XML on both sides.

Most browsers have DOMParser. But Node.js doesn't have a built-in XML parser. There are lots of modules for Node.js for XML parsing, but I'm looking for a XML parser API that is consistent for both front-end and back-end. In other words, I'm looking for a XML parsing module that can be used in Node.js like this

```
const parser = require(magic_library);
const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, 'application/xml');
```

and also in the browser like this

```
<script src="magic_library"></script>
<script>
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, 'application/xml');
</script>
```

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic], specifically item #4 in the section with the numbered list.

Comment: Try fast-xml-parser

Answer (score 2):

Try [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser)

In Node.js

```
var fastXmlParser = require('fast-xml-parser');
var jsonObj = fastXmlParser.parse(xmlData);

// when a tag has attributes 
var options = {
    attrPrefix : "@_",
    textNodeName : "#text",
    ignoreNonTextNodeAttr : true,
    ignoreTextNodeAttr : true,
    ignoreNameSpace : true,
    ignoreRootElement : false,
    textNodeConversion : true,
    textAttrConversion : false,
    arrayMode : false
};
if(fastXmlParser.validate(xmlData)=== true){//optional 
    var jsonObj = fastXmlParser.parse(xmlData,options);
}

//Intermediate obj 
var tObj = fastXmlParser.getTraversalObj(xmlData,options);
var jsonObj = fastXmlParser.convertToJson(tObj);
```

And in browser

```
var isValid = parser.validate(xmlData);
var jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData);
```

Comment: But note the limitations section: "The parser does not check whether the XML is valid or not". (And I suspect that by "valid", it means "well-formed"). Sadly, finding a high quality conformant XML parser for Javascript is very difficult (I haven't succeeded yet). And I won't believe a parser has a good level of conformance unless it publishes its results against the W3C conformance tests (https://www.w3.org/XML/Test/xmlconf-20020606.htm)

Comment: it depends on use cases. most performant parser usually sacrificing xml validation for speed.

Comment: I've taken a look at the source and this looks like something written by an amateur in an afternoon. It doesn't even handle basic things like character and entity references. The authors don't seem to know the proper meaning of the terms "well-formed" and "valid" as used in the XML world. And it doesn't produce a DOM tree, which is surely implicit in the OP's requirement.

Comment: Re-reading that comment: by "amateur" I didn't mean an amateur as far as programming skills are concerned, I meant someone whose knowledge of XML is fairly limited. Sorry if I implied otherwise.

Comment: How do I import this into the browser? I'm using Express. Do I just have a tag like. `<script src="../node_modules/fast-xml-parser"></script>`

Comment: @goodpoutine from readme, it says "Download and include parser.js"

Comment: @MichaelKay, you are right. the purpose of introducing `validator` function was just to validate the structure of the  current XML as a standalone file, not to verify it against the entity references. And I believe I had made the note it somewhere on the readme. If not I'll make that note. This library was created to provide the support to the other project [Stubmatic](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Stubmatic) but then separately published.

Comment: yeah I found it : "This library let you validate the XML data syntactically." I hope I'm grammatically correct.