# Are Angular lifecycle hooks called on every component of a nested component structure?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-lifecycle-hooks

This is just a conceptual question. I am trying to learn more about how Angular lifecycle hooks work.

My question is, if I have a nested component structure like below:

```
<parent-component>
    <first-child>
        <first-grandchild>
        </first-grandchild>
    </first-child>
    <second-child>
    </second-child>
</parent-component>
```

If eg the onChanges lifecycle hook is activated for one component, will it be activated for all child/sibling components?

If the answer to that is no, is there a non-hacky way to implement something to replicate that behaviour, or is it not supported?

Comment: May be xml-js works in the server side and not in the browser. You can check this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685100/xml-parser-that-works-for-both-browser-and-node-js

Comment: ```onChanges``` will get called immediately data-bound properties if at least one has changed. It will not be activicate/called for all child components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change detection flows from parent to child components. As for ngOnChanges lifecycle, it is called when a bounded property of a component(decorated with `@Input()` decorator) changes in the parent component.

This [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) explains it quite well.